# How do I make my Discord bot say a message every other Thursday at a specific time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to make my bot announce Rust server wipes. How do I schedule this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add your work

Comment: Check the current day of the week with `date.getDay()` every 24 hours and use a counter to run some code every 2nd Thursday. If you make a real attempt and it doesn't work you can try posting a more specific question that may get a real answer.

Comment: @Icehorn I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not very fluent in JS and I've been searching around Google with no luck.